# Обособление уточнений "На земле", "На верху"

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения, учебное-задание

"Внизу(,)на земле(,) вся лиственная мелочь показывает, что и у нее такие же почки, как у больших, и в красоте своей они внизу ничуть не хуже, чем там(,) наверху."

Нужно ли поставить запятые(те что в скобках), чтобы выделить уточнения? 
В электронных книгах где-то стоят, где-то нет.
У Розенталя в задачнике запятых нет. Помогите, пожалуйста, определиться.

И если запятые не ставятся, объясните почему "на земле" и "наверху" не являются уточнениями. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Внизу, на земле,** вся лиственная мелочь показывает, что и у нее такие же почки, как у больших, и в красоте своей они внизу ничуть не хуже, чем **там, наверху.**

1) Наречия ***на земле, наверху*** уточняют/поясняют значение **местоименных** наречий, то есть раскрывают их содержание.

Пример: А те, что ещё оставались **внизу, на земле,** истошно и тонко мычали, лезли и падали, пытались подняться и не могли. [Борис Екимов. Пиночет (1999)]

2) При отсутствии запятой мы имели бы **неоднородные отношения** (разные координаты), что  чаще возможно **для неместоименных наречий**,  например : Прежде чем я успел сообразить, что она собирается сделать, мы с Юркой увидели её уже **внизу на поляне.** [Виталий Губарев. (1950-1960)].

В то же время местоименные наречия в некоторых случаях также могут быть **неоднородными (выбор зависит от конкретного предложения),** например: Целый день простоял я **там на углу** ― всё без толку. [Марк Сергеев. (1971)]

Answer (score 3):

Являются уточнениями, запятые нужны. "Наверху" нужно писать слитно.